# Simplifying the inequality

Tags: inequality

I have a simple question but couldn't get it at all.
How can I simplify this therm?

$$\frac{x}{x^2-1} \ge \frac 1x$$

Comment: With the edit, the suggestion still stands... you can use cross multiplication while keeping track of the different cases to see whether or not the sign should have flipped in order to move everything to the top where things become clearer and easier to work with

Comment: Sry, I forgot the -1.

Comment: The method of solving rational inequalities remain the same:  move everything over to one side, write as a single rational expression, find the vanishing and undefined points, and use an interval table to determine the sign of the expression in each interval.

Comment: So... multiplying both sides by $(x^2-1)\cdot x$ you get $x^2 \lesseqgtr x^2-1$ where $\lesseqgtr$ is replaced by either $\leq$ or by $\geq$ depending on whether or not $(x^2-1)x$ was positive or negative...  From there, you should be able to see which values of $x$ make this true.

Comment: Do not multiply, subtract ! This gets reduced to $x(x+1)(x-1)>0$ (zero excluded, since we want to avoid any division by zero).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematics SE. I agree that you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem but in order to maintain this site as a repository of quality mathematical knowledge you should read this: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @zwim "*do not multiply, subtract!*"  I see no reason why you feel so strongly about that that you felt the need to include an exclamation point... the conclusion is easily reached by both methods.  It is clear that $x^2$ is in fact always strictly greater than $x^2-1$, so using the cross multiplication I suggested we see that the expression remains true iff the sign didn't change, i.e. what we multiplied by was positive... yielding the same $x(x+1)(x-1)>0$ that you did... The steps were effectively the same... just organized slightly differently.

Comment: @JMoravitz you give significance to meaningless stuff. I was just happy that in this case the subtraction was avoiding the discussion on reversing the inequalites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simplify $\frac{x}{x^2-1} \ge \frac 1x$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{x^2-1} &\ge \frac 1x\\
\frac{x}{x^2-1} - \frac 1x &\ge 0\\
\frac{x^2-(x^2-1)}{x(x^2-1)} &\ge 0\\
\frac{1}{(x-1)x(x+1)} &\ge 0\\
\Rightarrow \boxed{x\in(-1,0)\cup(1,+\infty)}
\end{align*}
Note that $x\neq0,-1,+1$ owing to the initial expression to be simplified.

Might as well draw the graphs of $\frac{x}{x^2-1}$ and $\frac 1x$ on the same axes for a better feel!

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than posting complete solution. Also, ask OP for his attempt or what more he knows about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).